# BizTalk 2009 Import/Copy failed as there are active/pending batches

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-deployment

I've been trying to redeploy an application and I finally got the application deleted, but I'm having problems.

Deploy works, but when I import bindings, or import an MSI before depoloyment, I get an error.

I tried stopping all other applications, stopping biztalk, etc... I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this error, ensure that all the batches in affected agreements are showing as stopped in the Agreement properties.

As per first google hit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg163219.aspx) :)

Look in your parties tab for any agreements setup.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found that earlier but I don't really know what an actual agreement is and there's really nothing else in BizTalk except this particular application.

Comment: Take a look in the "Parties" section of BizTalk - thats where business profiles are place, and any agreements should show in there.

Comment: You will probably have to stop the BizTalk hosts.  See http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jJkU_IdzDr0J:blog.hl7-info.com/2009/10/import_msi_and_getting_a_pendingactive_batches_error/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nz